# How to persist cognito user session in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuex, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Whilst learning Vue, I've gone in at the deep end and have gotten in to a little pickle...

I am trying to use **AWS Cognito** user pools to authenticate my app's sessions. So far I have managed to create a Userpool (in Cognito), create the custom login/out components within my Vue app and successfully login and out. The whole logging in process creates a few (about 10) key/value pairs in the browsers localStorage and this is where I'm struggling.

I need to **getItem** from *localStorage* and store it in Vuex so that when I do a *refresh* I am able to retrieve the token from state and **setItem** back to localStorage.

It all sounds terribly easy, though I'm currently finding myself learning Vue, Vuex and AWS services all at once which is adding a level of "blinkers" to my panic.

My current @click method goes like this...

```
signIn: function() {
    Auth.signIn(this.formResponses.username, this.formResponses.password)
        .then(user => {
            console.log(user);
            this.$store.state.signedIn = !!user;
            this.$store.state.user = user;
            this.signedIn = true;
            this.$store.state.token = user.signInUserSession.idToken.jwtToken;
            // this.currentUserInfo();
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend checking out [this walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzcG5Oe31bo) of how to add an auth workflow but the gist of it is that when a user tries to login you dispatch an action

```
async login(){
try{
await this.$store.dispatch('login', {formWithEmailAndPassword})
} catch(error){
console.log({error})
}
```

which calls "login" in your store that tries to use Amplify's Auth services (dont forget to import them with `import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify`):

```
export const actions = {
    async login({commit}, {email, password}){
    const user = await Auth.signIn(email, password)
    commit('set', user)
    return user
    }
...
```

which actually sets your user via "set":

```
export const mutations = {

    set(state,user){
    state.user = user
    }

...
```

Comment: What the difference between using cognito and amplify?